# WIN32 project - 'LNK1104 : cannot openmfc140d.lib' when I compile a project in my solution

Tags: c++, mfc, visual-studio-2019, win32gui, webview2

I used Visual Studio 2019. I've a WIN32 project. For this project, I used the Nuget manager to install Microsoft.Web.WebView2 (version 1.0.902.49) and Microsoft.Windows.ImplementationLibrary (version 1.0.210803.1) and in the project properties, here is the configuration :

[image: General configuration of my project]

Since I changed the property "Platform Toolset" from Visual Studio 2015 to Visual Studio 2019, I've an error at the compil : 'cannot open file mfc140d.lib'. I don't need MFC for this project. So, in the configuration of the linker, I decided to add in "Ignore Specific Default Libraries" the mfc140d.lib. And then, I tried to compil again but I got another error compil with another MFC dll.

Why do I get all those error message ? Why do I need MFC ? Can you explain what have I to do ?

Thank you

---

I've tried to uninstall the two packages Microsoft.Web.WebView2 and Microsoft.Windows.ImplementationLibrary and then, compil again but I've always got the same error message

Comment: Do the packages you have installed need the MFC ?

Comment: I've tried to uninstall the two packages Microsoft.Web.WebView2 and Microsoft.Windows.ImplementationLibrary and then, compil again but I've always got the same error message

Comment: Can you help me please ?

Comment: Use DependencyWalker https://www.dependencywalker.com/ to determine which component of your project requires the mfc dll.

Comment: @user2274060 "*I don't need MFC for this project*" - What is under *Advanced* for *Use of MFC*? "*I got another error compil with another MFC dll*" - Which other MFC dll?